# Prove $\exists\;E$ such that $\mu(E)=0$ and $\alpha=\sup\limits_{x\in X\backslash E} |f(x)|$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

$(X,\mathscr{M},\mu)$ is a measurable space and $f$ is a measurable function on $X$.  Denote by $$\alpha=\inf\{\sup\limits_{x\in X\backslash E} |f(x)| : E\in\mathscr{M}, \mu(E)=0\}.$$
Note that the infimum is taken over all measurable sets $E$ of measure zero.  If $\alpha<\infty$, then prove that there is $E\in\mathscr{M}$ with $\mu(E)=0$ such that $\alpha=\sup\limits_{x\in X\backslash E} |f(x)|$.

I was thinking proof by contradiction, assume $\alpha=\infty$ and construct a monotone, non-negative sequence $s_n$ such that $s_n\to f$. I'd reach a contradiction with $\alpha\not=\infty$. But I'm now thinking that does nothing for me. So I have no clue how to start this properly. Any help/advice would be good.

Comment: Proving $P\rightarrow Q$ by contradiction amounts to assuming not $Q$. Assuming $\alpha = \infty$ is assuming not $P$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $n\in\mathbb{N}=\left\{1,2,3,\ldots\right\}$ you can find $E_n\in\mathscr{M}$ such that $\mu(E_n)=0$ and $\alpha\leq\sup_{x\in X\setminus E_n}|f(x)|\leq\alpha+1/n$. Let $E=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}E_n$. Then $\mu(E)=0$, and for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $X\setminus E\subseteq X\setminus E_n$, therefore
$$\alpha\leq\sup_{x\in X\setminus E}|f(x)|\leq\sup_{x\in X\setminus E_n}|f(x)|\leq\alpha+1/n$$
Taking $\inf_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, you got the result.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: By definition of infimum, for any $n$ there is $E_{n}$ with $\mu (E_{n})=0$ such that $$\alpha \leq \sup_{X\setminus E_{N}} |f(x)| \leq \alpha + 1/n.$$

So we have a collection sets that gets closer and closer to what we want.